# '@material-ui/core' should be listed in the project's dependencies

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to add a Instagram-like like button to a component, but whenever I import the things I need from where I need them, this error pops up: "'@material-ui/core' should be listed in the project's dependencies."

The imports in question:

```
import FormControlLabel from '@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel';
import Checkbox from '@material-ui/core/Checkbox';
import Favorite from '@material-ui/icons/Favorite';
import FavoriteBorder from '@material-ui/icons/FavoriteBorder';
```

I've tried running 'npm i -S @material-ui/icons' and 'npm i -S @material-ui/core', even though they are already in the list of dependencies, as seen here:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
    "@fontsource/roboto": "^5.0.1",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.2.0",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.4",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.3",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.11.16",
    "@mui/material": "^5.13.2",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "firebase": "^8.2.0",
    "next": "12.0.7",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.4.0",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2"
  },
```

I've also tried formatting the import like this:

```
import { FormControlLabel, Checkbox } from '@material-ui/core';
import { Favorite, FavoriteBorder } from '@material-ui/icons';
```

I've also tried changing @material-ui to @mui in the imports, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Did you try delete `.next` folder and restarting the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As another comment had said, I just needed to delete the .next folder and restart the server.